# React-Native Fetch "POST" request throwing "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" in Android

Tags: json, http-post, react-native

**this is my function**
don't know where is the problem

```
fetchData() {
        fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Request : 'menu',
        active : '1',
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
              menu: responseData.Response,
          }); 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.warn('error',error);
    })
    .done();
      }
```

please point out the problem in function

Answer (score 5):

The error occcurs because your response cannot be casted to JSON format. This issue might happen because of wrong header, response body, or other various reasons based on your server. The way to go - since apparently the responses are not consistent - is to perform additional validation of server response before trying to cast the response to JSON.

You can do this by replacing:

```
.then((response) => response.json())
```

with

```js
.then((response) => {
  // In this case, we check the content-type of the response
  if (response.headers.get('content-type').match(/application\/json/)) {
    return response.json();
  }
  return response;
  // You can also try "return response.text();"
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
then((response) => response.json())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I think this is the problem
```

Responses with status code not equal to 2xx will not go into `catch` when you use fetch API, therefore you may JSON.parse something such as a HTML page or plain text stream.

You should check if `response.ok === true` before you parse response as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
    The error will be  occcurs because your response can not be casted to be JSON 
    format.

    there are  three  type of php mysqli api formate 

    1 formData 
    2 xml
    3 json 

   i think you  are use Formdata api  but you are request in json see  formdata  
    example

1) json Request..    example

        var Request = {
            security:1,
            token: token,
            email: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
          };
          console.log(JSON.stringify(Request));
                fetch(API.login, {
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify(Request)
                })
                  .then(res => res.json())
                  .then(res => {
                    console.log("Login RESPONCE:::  ", res);
                  }

      2)Formdata Example  use form data i think your error will be solve 

             let formdata = new FormData()

        formdata.append("Api variable",your post variable)
        formdata.append("name",this.state.name)
        formdata.append("email, this.state.email)
        formdata.append("password",this.state.password) 

       fetch('http://192.168.1.116/Restaurants/Registration.php', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        },
                        body:formdata


                    }).then(res => res.json())
                        .then(res => {


                            console.log('Data RESPONCE::', res);
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause of this error is your server not returning something that's not valid JSON (likely not JSON at all, like a 404 page or similar).

Comment: but on the postman i am having the response from my server @oblador

Answer (score 0):

If you set the request Content-Type to `application/json`, likely it will send a preflight request to check CORS.

In my React app (not React-Native), I got cross domain issue. My server doesn't support preflight request, and so the response looks like:

`{
  body: null,
  status: 0,
  ok: false,
}`

which is causing `response.json()` failed even though I got the expected JSON response in Chrome Dev Tools.

In my case, I change request Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which does not require a preflight request. It works as expected.

It might not help in your case but I hope it give you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Log responseData. It might be possible that API is returning invalid data.